# Using Far removed phrase

Tags: phrases

I want to say below sentence with using **far removed** phrase.

> I was soccer player when I was in collage but now I m basketball
>   player. So I m not that soccer player guy anymore.

can I say like:

> I m basketball player, I m much farther removed from soccer player than
>   i was in collage.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correct the grammar and spelling to

> I'm a basketball player: I'm much farther removed from a soccer player than I was in college.

you get something that is grammatical, and comprehensible, but unlikely that anybody would say it. It means something like:

> I'm a basketball player: I'm even less a soccer player than I was in college.

It implies that in college you were already not a soccer player, but now you are even further from being a soccer player. If that is what you intended, fine.

But I'm guessing that you actually meant to imply that at college you were a soccer player: if that is indeed your meaning, the sentence doesn't say it.

Comment: hmm yes, I meant to imply that at college i was a soccer player but I change and I m a basketball player now.

Answer (score 3):

It would sound more idiomatic this way:
"I'm a basketball player now--a far cry from the soccer player I was in college."

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+far+cry+from
a far cry from something
very different from something.   Playing in a comedy is a far cry from playing a criminal in a mystery.

Hope this helps, Mekici!

Giny

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and as such, you should always directly address the original question. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.